# change color of specific div dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i would like to change the `divs` color accordingly, dynamically if possible this is what i have so far:

**My database: shape**

```
id is_success
id1      0
id2      1
id3      0
id4      1

<div class="container" style="background: black; width: 500px; height: 500px;">
    
    <div style ="id="id1" width: 35%;  height: 14%; margin:20%"> div1 </div>
    <div style ="id="id1" width: 35%;  height: 14%; margin:80%"> div2 </div>
    <div style ="id="id1" width: 35%;  height: 14%; margin:10%"> div3 </div>
    <div style ="id="id1" width: 35%;  height: 14%; margin:60%"> div4 </div>
    
</div>

 <?php
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM shape ";
       
       if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
           while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
           {
              $id = $row['id'];
              $is_success = $row['is_success'];
              if ($is_success == 1)
              {
                  //change the divs background color to green
              }else {
                    //change the divs background color to red
              }
           }
       }
```

this is what the end result should look like this:

[image]

so when ever a value changes from the database the background color of the div should be set is this possible
**Updated**: Please Note that Each div are located at different positions on the html page

Comment: I don't really know about how SQL do anything, but you can just getElementById and set style background to the color you want

Comment: Put your HTML into the while-Loop :))

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have `width: 35%;` or  `height: 14%;`as HTML attributes. They must be inside the `stryle=""` attribute.

Comment: php can't manipulate client side html. You either us js(any js library) or make request to server each time something changes and return manipulated html with new value

Comment: Just put the divs inside the loop and set a class depending on how you want to style it .

Comment: I'm also guessing that you have removed some of the DB-code, since you're actually not executing the SQL query?

Comment: @droid fiji you wanna to just high light div by one by one?
why you are using Db?

Comment: Now you just put the id's inside the style attributes. Btw, id's needs to be _unique_ meaning that no two elements can have the same id. I would recommend you to read some basic HTML tutorials.

Comment: i have edited my question please have a look

Comment: ...and I have pointed new/more issues with it. Please make sure that you have the basis working before posting. Don't keep updating your question as an trail & error. SO isn't a syntax checker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="container" style="background: black; width: 500px; height: 500px;">
    <div style ="id="id1" width: 35%;  height: 14%;"> div1 </div>
    <div style ="id="id1" width: 35%;  height: 14%;"> div2 </div>
    <div style ="id="id1" width: 35%;  height: 14%;"> div3 </div>
    <div style ="id="id1" width: 35%;  height: 14%;"> div4 </div>
</div>

<?php
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM shape ";

   if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
       {
          $id = $row['id'];
          $is_success = $row['is_success'];
          if ($is_success == 1)
          {
              echo "<script>$('#id$id').css('color', 'green')</script>";
          }else {
              echo "<script>$('#id$id').css('color', 'red')</script>";
          }
       }
   }
```

Or you don't have to use jQuery or JavaScript at all. Simply put the HTML inside the loop.

```
<div class="container" style="background: black; width: 500px; height: 500px;">
 <?php
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM shape ";

       if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
           while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
           {
              $id = $row['id'];
              $is_success = $row['is_success'];
              if ($is_success == 1)
              {
                  echo "<div id=\"id$id\" style=\"width: 35%;  height: 14%; color: green\"> div$id </div>";
              }else {
                  echo "<div id=\"id$id\" style=\"width: 35%;  height: 14%; color: red\"> div$id </div>";
              }
           }
       }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: but can i make this dynamic some how or can maybe just refresh the class`container` every 5 seconds

Comment: @droidfiji You can. You can create an AJAX request to your server every 5 seconds and fetch the values and then use jQuery to change the values of the container.

Comment: Have a look at this. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Also you'd need a JavaScript's `setInterval()` method. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
       {
          $id = $row['id'];
          $is_success = $row['is_success'];
          $background = "background: red;";
          if ($is_success == 1)
          {
              $background = "background: green;";
          }
          ?>
          <div id="id1" width: 35%;  height: 14%; style="<?php echo $background ?>"> div1 </div>
          <?php
       }
```

Comment: Without the Else-Condition it will stay Green after the first Time the Condition is met.

Comment: No its loop so every time it will hold red first and if condition is true then only it will store green.

Comment: Yes, so this type of requirement if we add if and else then it will take bit more time to execute so thats fine I think. :)

Answer (score 1):

Parse your dynamic id to the respective div with background color.

```
$id = $row['id'];
$is_success = $row['is_success'];
if ($is_success == 1)
{
      // IF div id's and database id's are same try this line
      ?><script>$("#<?php echo $id;?>").css("background","green");</script><?php
      // Create new div with color dynamically try this line
      echo "<div id='".$id."' style='background:green;width: 35%;height: 14%; '> ".$id." </div>";
}else {
      ?><script>$("#<?php echo $id;?>").css("background","red");</script><?php
      // Create new div with color dynamically try this line
      echo "<div id='".$id."' style='background:red;width: 35%;height: 14%; '> ".$id." </div>";
}
```

Comment: this worked for me but is there away to make in dynamic

Comment: Your id is dynamic `<?php echo $id;?>` if you have color also dynamic `<?php echo $color;?>`

Comment: Considering that the OP has the same ID for all divs, (or currently, not having any id's at all since they are enclosed in the style-tag) this won't work on it's own. There are no connection between the divs and the db-results.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM shape ";

   if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
       {
          $id = $row['id'];
          $is_success = $row['is_success'];
          if ($is_success == 1)
          {
             echo "<div id='"id_.$id."'  style='background:green;width: 35%;  height: 14%; '> div1 </div>";
          }else {
               echo "<div id='"id_.$id."'  style='background:red; width: 35%;  height: 14%;'> div1 </div>";
          }
       }
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: Hi droid, your <div id="id_"> is dynamic you can see in the html.

Comment: There is no Need to write the Echo twice.

Comment: Hi Bernard, Why it is not required there is if condition and there are different background color in it. Please check it.

Comment: Yes but it is enough if you set the Variable in the If/Else and output the Line afterwards

Comment: `id='"id_.$id."'` = syntax error. Change it to: `id='id_{$id}'`

Comment: Oh sorry! my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

The short Way:

```
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo '<div id="id'.$row['id'].'" style="background-color: '.($row['is_success'] ? 'green' : 'red').';">div #'.$row['id'].'</div>';
       }
```

You can shorten the If/Else here by writing (condition ? true : false).